# Snowflake // How to count records for each view in given schema for DEV and PROD database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cursor, information-schema

I would like to compare the records count for each view in given schema between the databases: DEV and PROD. The goal is to verify if the corresponding views (in DEV and PROD) have the same record count.

Let say we have something like this:

Database_DEV.Schema.View01

Database_DEV.Schema.View02

Database_DEV.Schema.View03

and

Database_PROD.Schema.View01

Database_PROD.Schema.View02

Database_PROD.Schema.View03

And as a result I want to have a table like:

| ViewName | Database_DEV | Database_PROD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| View01 | 345 | 345 |
| View02 | 450 | 450 |
| View03 | 555 | 666 |

The view name should be taken dynamically from INFORMATION_SCHEMA table:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM Database_PROD.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE 1=1
AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'Database_PROD'
AND TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Schema'
```

I assume that I can get the result using cursor?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that I can get the result using cursor?

You could, but it would probably be easier to use a SQL generator and UNION ALL.

The SQL generator would look like this (change pattern to suit):

```
SELECT listagg('select \'' || TABLE_NAME || '\' as VIEW_NAME, (select count(*) from DB_PROD.PROD.' || TABLE_NAME || ') as PROD_COUNT, (select count(*) from DB_DEV.DEV.' 
               || TABLE_NAME  || ') as DEV_COUNT\n', 'UNION ALL\n') as SQL_TO_RUN
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE 1=1
AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'DB_PROD'
AND TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC'
;
```

The SQL generator will generate a single row and column to copy and paste or use in a script. It will look like this:

```
select 'MY_VIEW' as VIEW_NAME, (select count(*) from DB_PROD.PROD.MY_VIEW) as PROD_COUNT, (select count(*) from DB_DEV.DEV.MY_VIEW) as DEV_COUNT
UNION ALL
select 'MY_VIEW123' as VIEW_NAME, (select count(*) from DB_PROD.PROD.MY_VIEW123) as PROD_COUNT, (select count(*) from DB_DEV.DEV.MY_VIEW123) as DEV_COUNT
UNION ALL
select 'MY_VIEW456' as VIEW_NAME, (select count(*) from DB_PROD.PROD.MY_VIEW456) as PROD_COUNT, (select count(*) from DB_PROD.DEV.MY_VIEW456) as DEV_COUNT
UNION ALL
select 'MY_VIEW456' as DB_PROD.PROD.VIEW_NAME, (select count(*) from MY_VIEW789) as PROD_COUNT, (select count(*) from DB_DEV.DEV.MY_VIEW789) as DEV_COUNT
```

Running it produced output like this:

| VIEW_NAME | PROD_COUNT | DEV_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MY_VIEW | 25 | 25 |
| MY_VIEW123 | 25 | 25 |
| MY_VIEW456 | 25 | 25 |
| MY_VIEW789 | 50 | 50 |

You could even have the SQL generator add another column that compares the PROD_COUNT and DEV_COUNT and report true or false if they match or do not match.

Comment: Hi Greg, 
Thank you for your solution. That might be the right approach :)